# Asus Maximus Heroo VII stuck at splash screen

Tags: motherboard

I don't know whether I managed to kill my mobo after plugging in my external hard drive whilst in bios but now after reboot it is just stuck at the very first boot screen that shows Asus logo "Republic of Gamers" with "Press Del or F2 to enter Bios" and the keyboard does not respond at all.

The Mobo beeps once which I believe indicates everything is fine but clearly something is wrong because I can't get pass the splash screen and cannot get into bios either.

I tried unplugging RAM, all my hard drives, my graphics card but still the same issue.

Did my mobo die?

Edit:
I saw [somebody online](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/computer-freezes-at-motherboard-screen-cant-get-into-bios.3472169/) having exactly the same problem and the conclusion was that their board died.

Or it could be that my CMOS battery is low as this [person described](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/wont-boot-to-os-and-cant-enter-bios.2690169/). I will give it a try and get back.

Edit:
I replaced my CMOS battery and it didn't help.

It is also definitely not my keyboard. I tried another normal keyboard and it behaves the same way.

Comment: Verify that your boot order configuration is correct and update your question to provide that critical information

Comment: I can't even get into bios so can't verify that unfortunately

Comment: Since the reason I was asking for the boot configuration, is due to the fact I suspect, the configuration has been lost.  I would agree it's most likely the CMOS battery.

Comment: No info on the type of keyboard, but it is not beyond the possibility that you have a BT keyboard, and the BIOS reset has it disabled, in which case,hook up a wired one. Unlikely, but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it by resetting the mobo to stock and applying firmware updates again. I'm not sure what caused it to get stuck in the first place.